# How to create a non-component file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have question on react application architecture. I have some helper files and I don't want to use them as component, because they don't render anything. What I currently have is working, but I want to know opinions of my solution from professional react developers (or what should be better practice). I didn't find any solution on internet for my case...

I have several type of helper files:

constants.ts - contains constants like:

```
export enum ComponentType {
    TextField,
    SelectBox,
    ...
}
```

types.ts - contains types and interfaces, for example:

```
export type DBObject = {
    id: number,
    DBOClass: string,
    attributes: Array<DBObjectAttr>,
    editedAttrs: Array<DBObjectAttr>,
    isEdited: boolean
}

export interface BreadcrumbState {
    items: Array<BreadcrumbItemDef>
}
```

utils.ts - contains standalone helper functions like:

```
const getEnvironmentDomain = () => {
 some string operations...
}
```

XMLParser.ts - contains class XMLParser, which contains static method for parsing XML definition of form to javascript object:

```
export class XMLParser {
    ...

    public static parseXMLFormDefinitions = async (xmlStringDef: string): Promise<FormDefs> => {
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```

DBManager.ts - contains class DBManager for database manipulations; is full of static functions:

```
export class DBManager {
    ...    
    public static fetchFormDefinitions = async (): Promise<FormDefs> => { ... }
    public static getDBObjectDefinition = (DBOClass: string): DBObject => { ... }
    public static insertToDB = async (body: any, reload: boolean = true): Promise<any> => { ... }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, I export everything from that files and as you can imagine - I then import it in components where needed. But is it best practise how I designed that? And what is best place for them in project structure? Currently I have:

```
<src>/  
├── <components>/  
│   ├── <header>/  
│   ├── <card>/  
│   ├── ...  
├── <pages>/  
│   ├── <photos>/  
│   ├── <docs>/  
│   ├── ...  
├── <store>/  
│   ├── <reducers>/  
│       ├── BreadcrumbReducer.ts  
│       ├── DBObjectReducer.ts  
│       ├── ...  
│   ├── index.ts  
│   ├── sagas.ts  
├── constants.ts
├── types.ts
├── utils.ts
├── XMLParser.ts
└── DBManager.ts
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by non renderable components? I'm not sure to understand how it relates to what you are asking. From what I understand you are asking if your file structure follows best practices?

Comment: @SamiElk As you can see, those files are not component and doesn't render anything. My question is if it is OK, or should I convert them into react component somehow. I see now, that I have written confusing question title, I updated it...And second question is if my file structure (especially those helper files) follows best practices, as you have written.

Comment: @PetrMarek I don't know what kind of  other 'better' architecture you expect. What you are doing (*utils*, *helpers*, *constants* etc.), we all do that. So for now, worry not.

Comment: What I can say is : It is normal to have files that aren't component in your React project. Your ultimate goal is to have as little code duplication as possible. You can do that by extracting as much reusable code in helper functions as possible. Also it makes unit testing easier.

Comment: I know my questions can sound silly, but I didn't encouter similar helper files in react tutorials. Everywhere I read/listen only about component and everything inside them (even in advanced courses). So I was curious if real projects uses really only component or also helper files like I do...

Comment: No project structure is perfect it depends on your preferences and project size. When you find that a file for exemple `utils` becomes too big, you can separate it in multiple files in a helpers folder. In the end all subjective but I think you could find this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XEO3mFvrDx0&t=815s

Comment: Also you could go on GitHub and search for React projects and get an idea of how people structure their project. You can also learn a lot from trying to understand how other people code. For example search for `react opensource apps` on Google.

Answer (score 0):

As far as how I understood the questions this my answer.

I don't think there is the best practice, You can structure files how You want to, there are some conventions for structuring, and you don't have to use it if you don't want to.

And about 'helper' components, how you call them, You said in question

> I don't want to use them as component, because they don't render anything

Not rly sure what you do with them but they may be converted to custom hooks.

> A custom hook allows you to extract some components logic into a reusable function.

Quote above is from [this link](https://dev.to/damcosset/how-to-create-custom-hooks-in-react-44nd)

Or if you use them just as containers, div-s of some kind then think about using react Fragments. Read about fragments on [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)